# Globally determine if user is admin or not

Tags: laravel

I have a question.
I have table users.
And in table users I have `account_type` column.
I need determine if user is standard user, or administrator
How I can do it globally in the application?

Now I do this check in every file or controller:

```
if(auth()->user()->account_type == 0) { ... } else { ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Global Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#global-middleware)

- Create a Middleware, for Example :

  ```
     ...
     class PageAccess {
       public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
         if(auth()->user()->account_type == 0) { 
            return $next($request);
         } else {
            return redirect('/'); 
         }
       }
     }
  ```
- in `app/http/Kernel.php` add your Middleware

  ```
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
       ....

       'page_access' => \App\Http\Middleware\PageAccess::class,
   ];
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Base Controller and extends the BaseController to your all Contontroller like

```
Class UserController extends BaseController{
....
}
```

Look for **Laravel Repository Pattern**. It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) to define which user type can use the route.

And you can create a function in your user model to check the account type like this :

```
public function isAdmin(){
    return ($this->account_type == 1);
}
```

So when you need to check the account type you just have to use

```
auth()->user()->isAdmin()
```